# Confusion in invoking maven project

Tags: java, maven, google-chrome

I have a maven project which is running successfully on my system. This maven project takes any web URL as an input. Now I want to invoke this Maven project whenever my chrome extension is clicked. my chrome extension is capable of fetching the URL of the website.

So how can i do this? On searching google and many other resources, I came to know that I had to make a restful web service that can listen to the client side behavior.

But still I am not clear even how to do this? not even the initial steps are clear to me?

Any ideas would be greatly helpful to me!

I don't know anything about REST endpoint/postman, this was just the information, I gathered.

`P.S` if the scenario, I described is not clear, please comment, I would try to add more details.

**EDIT 1**

Here's my source code for JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

      chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
      alert(tabs[0].url)
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/SalesRESTservice/apicall/restcall2", true);
      req.onload = onResponseReceived;
      var par = 99.99;
      req.send(par);

        function onResponseReceived() {
            alert("It worked.");
        }
      // document.getElementById('Current_url').value = tabs[0].url;
      //console.log(tabs[0].url, tabs[0].title, tabs[0].incognito, tabs, this.bookmark_title);
    });
  });
```

And here's my JAVA endpoint code

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/restcall2")
public class restcall2 {

      @POST
      @Produces("application/json")
      public Response convertFtoC(Double param) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        Double fahrenheit = param;
        Double celsius;
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32)*5/9; 
        jsonObject.put("F Value", fahrenheit); 
        jsonObject.put("C Value", celsius);

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/json\") Output: \n\nF to C Converter Output: \n\n" + jsonObject;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
      }

}
```

I tried sending value of fahrenheit to java func., but it gives error?

console Error

```
INFO: Server startup in 1052 ms
May 27, 2016 1:54:17 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.Double, and Java type class java.lang.Double, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General

May 27, 2016 1:54:19 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.Double, and Java type class java.lang.Double, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

Comment: are you trying to test REST endpoint using postman or some other tool in chrome?

Comment: @BilboBaggins: I don't know anything about REST endpoint, this was just the information, I gathered.

Comment: I think the motive is clear, can you guide me how to accomplish that

Comment: to me, it is not clear, hope you can find you answer from the below given answers, if you don't then you need to clarify more on your motive ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a REST controller written, it should be up and listening to incoming requests. You need to provide those endpoint as request url and get information in your extension. You can use your browser directly or use extensions like POSTMAN to check and test your REST endpoints. And you can make an [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20140130/) from the chrome extension to your REST endpoints.

Example JS for invoking your REST API endpoint:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "http://api.myrestapi.com/services/rest/getEmployee", true);
req.onload = onResponseReceived;
req.send(null);

function onResponseReceived() {
    console.log("It worked.");
}
```

If you need to send with parameters using POST method try like this,

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var someValue = "99.99";
var url = "http://localhost:8080/SalesRESTservice/apicall/restcall2/"+param;
var params = JSON.stringify({ param: someValue });
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
        //or do some callback
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: Thanks very much but for writing REST controller, i have tried this http://ideone.com/gC5Exg, the server is running on the port but giving error " HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /hello. Reason:

    Server Error"

Comment: Is this the right way to write REST controller using jetty server?

Comment: No. You should clearly understand REST and how it works. Each endpoint is defined with `@Path` in the tutorial you have linked in your comments. First you need to go through that or if you are using spring please read this [Building a RESTful Webservice](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)  and test the API before you implement any of your code in chrome extension. Here's an example if you want to try in [jersey](http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/)

Comment: seems very useful links for a newbie like me. will definitely go through them. Thanks

Comment: @Lucky: I followed the tutorials and successfully made the REST controller, now as u said, in example JS for invoking REST API endpoint, I am unable to send parameter to my JAVA REST controller

Comment: I had added some more details on my question

Comment: @Prashant What error do you get? Did you test the API in browser before trying in the extension code? are you the OP of this question? If so you need to merge your accounts http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: No i am trying it in extension code, I had added the details of error which i am getting in console

Comment: @Lucky No I am not the opener of the question, but me and guru are from same technical team, so stuck on same problem and I decided to continue

Comment: @Lucky any ideas of why I am unable to send the pararmetrs

Comment: BTW, you are not sending any parameters from the JS code while the REST endpoint you have written expects a single parameter. What you are trying to do is send parameters in POST while your API and JS is using GET. Your url should look like `https://api.example.com/endpoint?a=1&b=2&c=3`. So try `http://localhost:8080/SalesRESTservice/apicall/restcall2?param=99.99`.

Comment: still not working...you mean req.send(par); does not send the single paramter form js call to REST endpoint? Meanwhile i had changed the js code to POST rather than GET and also java code

Comment: No you don't need POST. You can do this in GET itself. But does the POST method work?

Comment: _both are not working_ What error do you get in the console? Do you see a request fired in the network tab in developer console?

Comment: same, which i added in question, same error messages

Comment: you mean using GET in js code right or in js as well as java?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113122/discussion-between-lucky-and-guru).

Comment: Done Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: @Lucky: can you come on chat online?

Answer (score 1):

Start with https://jersey.java.net/
Jersey RESTful Web Services framework is open source.
You will get a brief idea from there.

Further you can get the basic jersey web application here 
https://github.com/Vijendra07Kulhade/jersey-quickstart

Simply clone it and run maven install.

For running your maven project add below plugin in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </plugin>
```

You can take the reference from above github repo.

run command `mvn tomcat7:run`
It will run your project in tomcat. It will also tell the context where it deployed. something like below. you can hit this from postman.

```
localhost:8080/someContext/
```

Comment: u mean the provided github repo will be able to take URL as input whenever, I would click chrome extension?

Comment: No, Sorry I got your question wrong. I was giving input to create a restful web application. Looks like you already have it. I am not sure if you are looking for this. But you need to run application in to some server and its end point url you can hit from chrome extension postman.

Comment: Yes, can you tell me how to run my maven project in to some server and also how to hit the endpoint URL from chrome extension postman

Comment: I have been following this http://jlunaquiroga.blogspot.in/2014/01/restful-web-services-with-jetty-and.html

Comment: As far as running the application is concerned I can see there is a main method in this class (not a client) MinimalServerRest, you can directly run this method.

Comment: this is not the application which i am trying to run, this is the REST controller I am trying to make using jetty http://ideone.com/gC5Exg

Comment: @VijendraKulhade: Thanks for your insights but my REST controller is not listening

Comment: @VijendraKulhade: how can i run your REST service which you provided in github link? I mean import it as Maven project in netbeans or any other?